# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x - \cos^{-1} (e^{-\frac x2})}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

The limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x -0}{x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{2x}$$
$$=0$$

$0$ is not the right answer. I think my mistake was in the first step, but I couldn’t think of anything else.

Comment: you can't just evaluate the arccos to 0, you still need to take derivatives of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that as $x\to 0^+$

$$\cos^{-1} (e^{-\frac x2})=\sqrt x -\frac1{12}x^{\frac32}+o(x^2)$$

therefore the right limit is $-\infty$.

The left limit doesn’t exist since $e^{-x/2}\to 1^+$.

Refer to the related

- [Taylor expansion of $\arccos(1-x)$ around $x=0$ to two terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255886/505767)

---

As an alternative since

$$\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}\to 0$$

by $-\frac x2=\log(\cos y)$ as $y\to 0^+$ we have

$$\frac{-\cos^{-1}\left(e^{-\frac x2}\right)}{x^2}=-\frac{y}{4\log^2\cos y}$$

which can be easily solved by l’Hospital.

Comment: How did you write the expansion? did you use the expansion of arccos and then $e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$

Comment: I add the source for that!

Comment: @user Another way (rather strenous) is to use $t=e^x$ substituition and then use L-Hospitals rule twice to get $- \infty$.But your method is better!

Comment: Is there any way other an expansion, since the expansion can’t always be easily determined? L Hospital is way too tedious

Comment: @Aditya Yes we can simplify that by substitution. I add something on that.